# Differentiating に訪れる vs. を訪れる

Tags: particle-に, particle-を

From the first episode of Death Note:

> しいて言えば そのノートを使った
> **人間にしか訪れない**苦悩や恐怖

**Question:** Why is に here used instead of を? Or perhaps more simply, what is the difference between

1. 人間に訪れる
2. 人間を訪れる

**EDIT:** Is に preferred here with 人間 "human" because using を "treats the human as a mere object" (i.e. like a place one is visiting, rather than respectfully as a human being, or something like that)?

Comment: 人だけじゃなく、「蔵王温泉**に**冬が訪れました」とか言いますね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

明鏡国語辞典 says:

> おと‐ず・れる【訪れる】
> 〘**自**下一〙〔雅語的な言い方で〕**季節・時間・状況などがやってくる**。
> 「北国**に**もまもなく春が訪れる」「ついに彼ら**に**も破局が訪れた」
> 〘**他**下一〙〔雅語的な言い方で〕**人がある場所や人の居所を[訪]{たず}ねる**。
> 「月に一度は京都**を**訪れる」「相談事があって田中家**を**訪れる（=訪問する）」
> 語法「多くの外国人が京都**に**観光に訪れています」など、まれに自動詞としても使う。

So 訪れる as "a season, time or situation comes around" is an intransitive verb and takes に, and as "one visits a place or someone's place" it's a transitive verb and takes を. (In 語法 it says 訪れる as the second definition can also take に.)

> 人間にしか訪れない苦悩や恐怖
> ⇒「人間**に**苦悩や恐怖が訪れる」

It's not that 苦悩や恐怖が人の居所を訪ねる・訪問する but 苦悩や恐怖の状況・時を人間が経験する, so I think this 訪れる is definition #1.

> 「人間に訪れる」
> 「人間を訪れる」

人間に訪れる sounds to me as 「人間に時がやってくる」 or 「人間がそれを経験する」. 「〇〇さん（の家）を訪れる」「〇〇屋さんを訪れる」 means you go to the person's place, house or shop.